# How to deploy NEXTJS app on Google hosting if it contains [id].js page?

Tags: next.js

I have an application which uses Google hosting. Prior to implementing dynamic routes I hosted it by executing `next export` and `firebase deploy`.

In my `[id].js` file I get data by using `getServerSideProps` and while executing `next export` I've got the next error:

> pages with getServerSideProps can not be exported [Read More](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/master/errors/gssp-export.md).

And the solution is to "delete `next export` from package.json". But How can I host my app without `next export` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found just one solution for this situation, it is the using `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths` instead of `getServerSideProps`, here's example from [official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching) how to use it properly:

```
// pages/posts/[id].js

function Post({ post }) {
  // Render post...
}

// This function gets called at build time
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  // Call an external API endpoint to get posts
  const res = await fetch('https://.../posts')
  const posts = await res.json()

  // Get the paths we want to pre-render based on posts
  const paths = posts.map((post) => ({
    params: { id: post.id },
  }))

  // We'll pre-render only these paths at build time.
  // { fallback: false } means other routes should 404.
  return { paths, fallback: false }
}

// This also gets called at build time
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  // params contains the post `id`.
  // If the route is like /posts/1, then params.id is 1
  const res = await fetch(`https://.../posts/${params.id}`)
  const post = await res.json()

  // Pass post data to the page via props
  return { props: { post } }
}

export default Post
```

Answer (score 0):

why not hosting your app on vercel? it makes everything so easy. if you really want to host it on google, replace getServerSideProps by getStaticProps or with client side rendering

Comment: with getStaticProps i have to use getStaticPaths, but how can i use getStaticPaths with dynamic data ?

Comment: Just add all your data in getStaticPaths, for example if you have a dynamic page named [id], in getStaticPaths you will add all the id of your data so that you can use getStaticProps with dynamic data. it's mentioned in the doc, you can check it here https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching

Comment: Here is the example if you want to host on google
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-firebase-hosting

Comment: @Beloved yeah, you are right! I was googling and didn't find any solution with getServerSideProps, i used getStaticProps with getStaticPaths, where i generate all possible paths based on my data inside, please update your answer with example and i will mark it as solution.